# How to code fortran to read a data file and print certain rows?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, data-files

I have created a code that reads in a data file and print out the 20 lines of it. I want to develop this by making the code read all the lines within the data file, and only printing out certain lines that comply with an if statement. There are 4 values per data row, and I want it to look at the 3rd value and see if this changes, and if it does then to print that row of values. Can anyone help?

```
  program datafile

  implicit none
  real*8 um,nm,pN,s
  integer*8 au
  integer*8 i
  real, dimension(1:4)
  real, dimension(4) :: file

  WRITE(*,*)"test"
  OPEN(UNIT=1, FILE="file.dat",STATUS="old",ACTION="read")
  WRITE(*,*)"file opened"


  do i=1,20
     read(1,*) file


     write(*,*)file
  enddo

  close(unit=1)
  end program datafile
```

~

Comment: Regrettably, this site is not about teaching you to code. You can try to find tutorials for this or go to a coding help site. If you try to code this yourself and get unexpected results, you can ask here again.
Welcome to stackoverflow. I suggest you take the [tour.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Please ask a question that can be answered. *Can anyone help?* is not such a question. See [ask].

Comment: If you are not going to take a crack at doing the homework, then you won't learn. I can tell that that code will not compile just looking at it.